# How to assign a number to an element in an array

Tags: java

I have a task to solve this problem:

This code should me in Runner and I have to write code, and then when i will write this in main:

```
Figure[] figures = { createCircle(10), createRectiangle(10,20), createSquare(15)};

for(Figure f : figures){
System.out.println(f)
}
```

I should get:

```
Figure number 1: Circle with a radius of 10.
Figure number 2: Rectangle 10x20.
Figure number 3: Square 15.
```

I did everything good but I dont know what should I do to get this number 1, 2 and 3.

I mean that i dont know how I can count numbers.

How can I do it to display the number of an element in the table next to the appropriate figure, i.e. if I change the order of creating elements, the number will always be from 1 to 3.

Comment: Use a regular `for` loop: `for i=1; i<=3; ++i)` and access your array elements as `figures[i]`.

Comment: You need to convert to a regular `for` loop in order to get access to the indexes. `for (int i = 0; i < figures.length; i++)`. Remember, the indexes are zero-indexed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a for-each loop if you want a number

```
for (int i = 0; i < figures.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Figure number %d: %s.%n", i, figures[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am not able to edit it. I can't change it. I have to write code to make it wroking. I have ot use this for-each

Comment: Maybe I shoud do something in the toString method>

Comment: You need to edit code to add a number in the output. If you are required to use a for-each, set an integer outside of it, then increment inside after you print it